# How to get values on selected multiple dropdown using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I can only get the last selected value on my select multiple *dropdown*.

I have tried answers on the forum but no luck.

**My HTML:**

```
<select id="provider" class="validate" multiple required>
  <option value="" disabled>Invoice Provider Name</option>
  <option>Provider 1</option>
  <option>Provider 2</option>
</select>
```

**My JS:**

```
function addRow(){
  var x=document.getElementById("provider");
  var pro = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < x.options.length; i++) {
    if(x.options[i].selected ==true){
      pro = x.options[i].length.value;
    }
  }
}
```

assuming that I selected *Provider 1*, *Provider 2* on the *dropdown*, I want to get

```
Provider 1
Provider 2
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please add the HTML select element as well. As for your problem, pro is a 'string' type variable. It can store only one value which gets over written.

Comment: Added HTML. How can I made pro to hold multiple values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with [**`Array.prototype.filter()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

And [**`Array.prototype.map()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

Try the following way:

```js
document.getElementById('provider').addEventListener('change', function(){
  console.clear();
  let selected = [...this.options].filter(option => option.selected).map(o => o.value);
  console.log(selected);
});
```

```html
<select id="provider" class="validate" multiple required>
  <option value="" disabled>Invoice Provider Name</option>
  <option>Provider 1</option>
  <option>Provider 2</option>
</select>
```

In your way by declaring an array and pushing option's *value* to the array if selected:

```js
function addRow(el){
  var x = el;
  var pro = []; // create an array
  for (var i = 0; i < x.options.length; i++) {
    if(x.options[i].selected == true){
      pro.push(x.options[i].value); // push the value to the array
    }
  }
  console.log(pro);
}
```

```html
<select id="provider" class="validate" multiple required onchange="addRow(this)">
    <option value="" disabled>Invoice Provider Name</option>
    <option>Provider 1</option>
    <option>Provider 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I wanna get specific select multiple dropdown via ID. Is this possible with your code?

Comment: Instead of using `document.querySelector('select')`, you can use `document.querySelector('#provider')`

Comment: @RJVillamer, like the previous comment from Krishna Prashatt, updated the answer, please check:)

Comment: I suggest changing query selector to `getElementById` as it's much faster. And changing `o.text` to `o.value`

Comment: :) I would upvote again if I could. I would also recomment not using `this` in that function. Instead I would change it to `.addEventListener('change', ev => { const sel = ev.target; ...`

Comment: Thanks for your answers. However, I would like to call the selected1 variable inside my "data" variable which is an array. Can you confirm if I did it correctly?

https://img.techpowerup.org/190806/capture.jpg

Comment: @RJVillamer, there is no `selected1` and `data` variable in your code, it not clear to me, could you elaborate it?

Comment: @RJVillamer, please check the third answer:)

Comment: @Mamun, document.getElementByID.("provider") is not present, will still it work?

Comment: @RJVillamer, no, if the element is not present how will it work?

Comment: @RJVillamer, what do you mean by *how can I place the element to make it work?*

Comment: @Mamun nevermind, I am getting [Ljava.lang.Object;@12bda76c as the value. Any ideas? This is what I did.

https://img.techpowerup.org/190806/capture932.jpg